Optimizing Functions for Network Graphs
In this question here (Summing Nodes in a Network), I learned how to find the square within the original network having the largest node sum.
Here is the data for this question:
library(igraph)

width <- 30
height <- 20
num_nodes <- width * height

# Create a grid
x <- rep(1:width, each = height)
y <- rep(1:height, times = width)

g <- make_empty_graph(n = num_nodes, directed = FALSE)

# Function to get node index
get_node_index <- function(i, j) (i - 1) * height + j

# Add edges
edges <- c()
for(i in 1:width) {
   for(j in 1:height) {
      current_node <- get_node_index(i, j)
    
      # Connect to right neighbor
      if(i < width) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i + 1, j))
    
      # Connect to bottom neighbor
      if(j < height) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i, j + 1))
   }
}

g <- add_edges(g, edges)

V(g)$x <- x
V(g)$y <- y

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

V(g)$name <- 1:num_nodes
plot(g, vertex.size = 7, vertex.label = V(g)$name, vertex.label.cex = 0.6, main = "Map with         Node Indices")

V(g)$value <- sample(1:100, num_nodes, replace = TRUE)
plot(g, vertex.size = 7, vertex.label = V(g)$value, vertex.label.cex = 0.6, main = "Map with     Population Values")

And here is the function:
sg <- subgraph_isomorphisms(make_ring(4), g)
lst <- unique(lapply(sg, \(x) sort(names(x))))
out <- do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    lst,
    \(v) data.frame(
      node_id = toString(v),
      value = sum(V(induced_subgraph(g, v))$value)
    )
  )
)

This approach is currently using a brute force style approach in which every node is individually checked. Are there any ways in R to restructure this function so that it runs in parallel or a different type of search algorithm that can scan the network more efficiently?
I had two ideas about this:

Idea 1:
Rewriting the function to look at square grids and tesselate them over the network:
 efficient_sum_squares <- function(g, width, height) {
   results <- data.frame(node_id = character(), value = numeric())

   for (i in 1:(width - 1)) {
     for (j in 1:(height - 1)) {
       nodes <- c(
         get_node_index(i, j),
         get_node_index(i + 1, j),
         get_node_index(i, j + 1),
         get_node_index(i + 1, j + 1)
       )

       sum_value <- sum(V(g)$value[nodes])

       results <- rbind(results, data.frame(node_id = toString(nodes), value = sum_value))
     }
   }

   results
 }

 out_efficient <- efficient_sum_squares(g, width, height)


Idea 2:
I thought that comparisons could be carried out in a vectorized fashion:
 vectorized_sum_squares <- function(g, width, height) {
   x_mat <- matrix(V(g)$x, nrow = height, ncol = width, byrow = FALSE)
   y_mat <- matrix(V(g)$y, nrow = height, ncol = width, byrow = FALSE)
   value_mat <- matrix(V(g)$value, nrow = height, ncol = width, byrow = FALSE)

   sums <- value_mat[1:(height-1), 1:(width-1)] + 
           value_mat[2:height, 1:(width-1)] + 
           value_mat[1:(height-1), 2:width] + 
           value_mat[2:height, 2:width]

   node_ids <- apply(which(sums == sums, arr.ind = TRUE), 1, function(idx) {
     i <- idx[1]
     j <- idx[2]
     toString(c(
       get_node_index(j, i),
       get_node_index(j + 1, i),
       get_node_index(j, i + 1),
       get_node_index(j + 1, i + 1)
     ))
   })

   data.frame(node_id = node_ids, value = as.vector(sums))
 }

 out_vectorized <- vectorized_sum_squares(g, width, height)



Is there any better way to work on this problem?

In case you didn’t know, I would recommend checking out Code Review. Your question seems to be reasonably suited for that community as well.

You have too many things in your question, which distract the audiences and make them lose the focus. I think you can simplify your question by just saying "find the 4-node square in a grid that yields the largest sum weights of the vertices: how to improve the efficiency?". You don't need to put many details, but a reproducible minimal example, the objective, and the expected output should be enough.

If you search such squares (consisting of 4 adjacent nodes) in a grid, I don't you really need igraph at all. The 2nd idea is good enough if you work with a matrix only, and igraph operations can be avoided.
Here is an example similar to 2nd approach
set.seed(0)
width <- 15
height <- 10
gmat <- matrix(sample.int(10, width * height, replace = TRUE), height)

ul <- gmat[-height, -width]
ur <- gmat[-height, -1]
dl <- gmat[-1, -width]
dr <- gmat[-1, -1]

ssum <- ul + ur + dl + dr
idx <- apply(
  which(ssum == max(ssum), TRUE),
  1,
  \(x) {
    toString(crossprod(
      c(height, 1),
      x + cbind(
        c(-1, 0),
        c(-1, 1),
        c(0, 0),
        c(0, 1)
      )
    ))
  }
)

res <- data.frame(node_id = idx, value = max(ssum))

and you see that
> gmat
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
 [1,]    2    3    1    2    3    3    2    1    1     3     1     2     3
 [2,]    1    3    3    2    2    3    1    1    1     2     2     1     1
 [3,]    3    1    1    1    1    2    3    1    1     2     2     3     1
 [4,]    1    1    1    3    3    2    3    1    1     2     1     3     2
 [5,]    2    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     3     3     1     2
 [6,]    1    2    1    3    1    2    3    2    2     2     3     2     2
 [7,]    3    2    2    2    1    1    3    3    1     2     2     1     1
 [8,]    3    2    1    2    3    2    2    1    1     3     3     3     1
 [9,]    2    2    1    2    2    2    3    1    3     3     2     2     1
[10,]    2    3    2    2    2    2    3    2    3     3     1     3     2
      [,14] [,15]
 [1,]     1     2
 [2,]     3     2
 [3,]     2     1
 [4,]     3     2
 [5,]     3     3
 [6,]     2     3
 [7,]     3     3
 [8,]     3     3
 [9,]     1     3
[10,]     1     1

and
> res
          node_id value
1 89, 90, 99, 100    12
2  74, 75, 84, 85    12

